# How to redirect to login with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

my app has no home so want to redirect to "/login" when user access path "/".
The route path is now home.

```
const Routes = () => (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        component={Login}
        render={() => path="/" && <Redirect to="/login" />}
      />
```

I can't remove `component={Login}` from `Route`, get a typescript error.
Does anyone know other way to redirect to login?

Comment: you should not be using both the component and render at the same time . use either one or the other . Also when you want to redirect ? .

Comment: Also, you should write `path === "/"`

Comment: Thank you. I want to make redirect to login when user access to "/" path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved with this code.

```
<Route exact path="/">
  <Redirect to="/login" />
</Route>
```